# provide teamsite template trough sitescript: cannot convert Object[] to string

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-provision, site-script

I made a (simple) sitescripttemplate in JSON which I would like to make available for all the users who can create a site.

The inconvenience lies in the fact I only got it working which I write the whole jsoncode in the same PS1 file.

Rather I would prefer to load a file from a directory and work with that content. As you see in my code below

```
$site_script = Get-Content -Path "./siteTemplate1.json"

$SiteScript = Add-SPOSiteScript  -Title "SiteTemplate1"  -Content $site_script  -Description "SiteTemplate1" 

Add-SPOSiteDesign  -Title "SiteTemplate1"  -WebTemplate "64"  -SiteScripts $SiteScript.Id  -Description "SiteTemplate1"
```

error I get

```
Add-SPOSiteScript : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Content'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:1 char:78
+ ... ipt  -Title "SiteTemplate_JoinHubSite"  -Content $site_script  -Descr ...
+                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-SPOSiteScript], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.AddSPOSiteScript
```

Thank you Hero to look in to this...

Comment: Modify it as `$site_script = Get-Content -Path "./siteTemplate1.json" -Raw` and try

Comment: Oh boy... shame on me to overlook this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also pass `-Raw` parameter to the get content for Site Script.

So, modify your code as:

```
$site_script = Get-Content -Path "./siteTemplate1.json" -Raw
```

When you use the Raw parameter, it returns the value as one string which can then be passed to the `Add-SPOSiteScript` command.